# How to make CORS Authentication in WebAPI 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

The scenario is simple, I need to log in from another server (different from the API server) to retrieve the access token.

I installed `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` package on the API Server. In `Startup.Auth.cs` file, under `public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)`, I added in

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

In `WebApiConfig.cs`, under `public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)`, I added in these lines:

```
// Cors
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

What else should I change?

Comment: app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll) - enables CORS for all cross-origins requests to your site. config.EnableCors(..) enables CORS for Web Api only

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Look at what I have found!

Add in some custom headers inside `<system.webServer>`.

```xml
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Then I can do the CORS authentication.

Comment: I have no idea how I would have figured this out without your post; thank you! The web API documentation doesn't mention these configuration requirements...http://goo.gl/s9K6o2 & http://goo.gl/G8jKG0

Comment: Unfortunately, as much as people are saying not to do this, something along the OWIN authentication pipeline is 1) Overriding any response I've already written via context.Request.Headers as part of OWIN middleware 2) Even with custom policies configured, ignoring OWIN cors for the "/token" request.  At least for testing purposes, I'm not sure I have much a choice for now.

Comment: I think what really should happen is, we should wrap token method to account controller with something called login, then the standard cors configuration would do the job.

Comment: if you have app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll) , you only need to add Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Comment: This is not a great solution. It works but it is the equivalent of turning off your firewall instead of configuring it properly.

Comment: I disagree. CORS isn't a solution to anything. A firewall protects the client, but CORS is (mis)used as a way to protect the server, but a simple client change of the request headers and you are golden. Just use e.g. chrome --disable-web-security flag or search for Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * Chrome extension.

Comment: Why is this so vehemently upvoted, this is NOT a solution. This completely overrides any CORS middleware configuration.

Comment: @Mardoxx Would one of you care to share the correct solution?

Comment: @Mardoxx lot at my answer below.

Comment: So what's the damn solution then?

Comment: As I needed to get something quick and dirty working fast, this was very useful. I had to add `Content-Type` to the header list to get it to work with `fetch` though.

Answer (score 52):

I had many trial-and-errors to setup it for AngularJS-based web client.
For me, below approaches works with ASP.NET WebApi 2.2 and OAuth-based service.

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` nuget package.
2. Install `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` nuget package.
3. Add `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"));` to the above of `WebApiConfig.Register(config);` line at **Startup.cs** file.
4. Add `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` to the **Startup.Auth.cs** file. This must be done prior to calling `IAppBuilder.UseWebApi`
5. Remove any xml settings what Blaise did.

I found many setup variations and combinations at here stackoverflow or [blog articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx). So, Blaise's approach may or may not be wrong. It's just another settings I think.

Comment: This might create the following problem: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1539

Comment: I have enabled CORS in my OWIN and Web API configs using `app.UseCors` and `config.EnableCors` methods, respectively, but the OWIN `/token` endpoint appears to be treated specially and is not sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP Header in the response.  This is true even when implementing the custom policy solution by Konstantin Tarkus below.

Comment: You need a Nuget package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" to have classes and method for step 1.

Comment: I had to install `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` as well

Answer (score 35):

After many hours of searching and looking at many many different solutions to this i have managed to get this working as per the below.

There are a number of reasons this is happening. Most likely you have CORS enabled in the wrong place or it is enabled twice or not at all.

If you are using Web API and Owin Token end point then you need to remove all the references to CORS in your Web API method and add the correct owin method because web api cors will not work with Token endpoint whilst Owin cors will work for both Web API and Token auth end points so lets begin:

1. Make sure you have the Owin Cors package installed Remove any line
   that you have eg.config.EnableCors(); from your WebAPIconfig.cs file
2. Go to your startup.cs file and make sure you execute Owin Cors
   before any of the other configuration runs.

   app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
   ConfigureAuth(app);
3. If your still having problems go to: Startup.Auth.cs and ensure you have the following in your ConfigureAuth method (you shouldnt need this if your startup.cs file is correct)

`app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

Comment: Thanks @Piotr, This is the real working answer.
Can Blaise please mark this as the real answer? with all other answers, either OWIN /Token OR WebAPI works while they can't work together. In my case, adding XML in Web.config plus config.EnableCors(...) causes duplicated header [Access-Control-Allow-Headers] being added, which is prohibited in Chrome.

Comment: I too face faced duplicate header issue after including both OWIN and Web API Cors in the project. But as @Piotr stated in the answer, only OWIN CORS is enough to take care of it.

Comment: This is the best answer Thank you very much Additionally you may need  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost package and Microsoft.Owin.Cors package to use   UseCors Function of IAppBuilder (app)

Answer (score 23):

#### web.config

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="cors:Origins" value="*" />
  <add key="cors:Headers" value="*" />
  <add key="cors:Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
</appSettings>
```

#### Startup.cs

```cs
var appSettings = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

// If CORS settings are present in Web.config
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appSettings["cors:Origins"]))
{
    // Load CORS settings from Web.config
    var corsPolicy = new EnableCorsAttribute(
        appSettings["cors:Origins"],
        appSettings["cors:Headers"],
        appSettings["cors:Methods"]);

    // Enable CORS for ASP.NET Identity
    app.UseCors(new CorsOptions
    {
        PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
        {
            PolicyResolver = request =>
                request.Path.Value == "/token" ?
                corsPolicy.GetCorsPolicyAsync(null, CancellationToken.None) :
                Task.FromResult<CorsPolicy>(null)
        }
    });

    // Enable CORS for Web API
    config.EnableCors(corsPolicy);
}
```

**Note**: `app.UserCors(...)` should be called before configuring ASP.NET Identity.

#### Source: [ASP.NET Web Application Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/AspNet-Server-Template) (ASP.NET Web API, Identity, SignalR)

Comment: I've implemented this and am surprised to find that, verifying policy code execution is valid in the debugger, there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the HTTP response for the "/token" request.

Comment: Strangely, after enabling CORS via web.config by adding the response header manually, not through any OWIN or Web API CORS configuration, then removing that and re-enabling my API configurations, the problem with "/token" went away.  Not sure what's going on, but the issue's gone now.

Comment: Keep in mind that the order where you place `.EnableCors()` in your OWIN pipeline does matter. You want to put it before other OWIN middleware stuff.

Comment: is this the web.config for the api website or for the client website?

Comment: @KonstantinTarkus Hi, I want to only allow http requests from certain url. what should I put in place of value in <add key="cors:Origins" value="*" />. The only url that can make request is localhost:777. ?

Answer (score 16):

To elaborate on Youngjae's answer, there's a great tutorial on setting up OWIN with Web API and enabling CORS in the process at http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

You'll want to add the NuGet package for CORS with the command:
`Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors -Version 2.1.0`

Then add
`app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

to your Configuration method in Startup.cs so it looks something like:

```c#
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    ConfigureOAuth(app);
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. And I think the original question was exactly about this why app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); does not work.

Comment: I have enabled CORS in my OWIN and Web API configs using `app.UseCors` and `config.EnableCors` methods, respectively, but the OWIN `/token` endpoint appears to be treated specially and is not sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP Header in the response.  This is true even when implementing the custom policy solution by Konstantin Tarkus below.

Answer (score 9):

The answer for me was found at

[Web Api 2 Preflight CORS request for Bearer Token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26980271/4413476)

Specifically, the /Token request using an implementation of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials was adding the header in again. Add the OWIN CORS stuff before any other OWIN config, and remove the header from GrantResourceOwnerCredentials, as per that link, and voila. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

I just want to share my experience. I spent half of the day banging my head and trying to make it work. I read numerous of articles and SO questions and in the end I figured out what was wrong.

The line

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

was not the first one in `Startup` class `Configuration` method. When I moved it to the top - everything started working magically.

And no custom headers in `web.config` or `config.EnableCors(corsPolicy);` or anything else was necessary.

Hope this will help someone to save some time.

Comment: saved me 30 mins before my assignment was due :) thanks! #magic lol

Comment: Even if I add this as the 1st line in the startup class configuration method, I get the error. But when I add the config along with this line it starts throwing the duplicate issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can find here the multiple ways you have to enable CORS at different scopes: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Anyway I had the same issue, and by adding the headers in different ways didn't get the complete solution.

I found out that the IIS uses handlers which overrides your CORS web app config if you don't specify the opposite.

In my case, I also had to remove the usage of IIS handlers by adding the following configuration at the main Web.config of my application:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Be aware that this configuration may be set by default when you create a new project depending on the type of it, but if you start from scratch you probably will have to add this config.

Comment: Yes! This has been bugging me so much, using JSONP while I'm developing. Started from scratch as you say.

Answer (score 2):

Adding customer Headers might not give you as much freedom in customize your security needs. It opens up all other part of the api to the world. The following code only does that for "token", and controller other part of api should be done via EableCors annotation.

```c#
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //other stuff
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        IOwinRequest req = context.Request;
        IOwinResponse res = context.Response;
        if (req.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/Token")))
        {
            var origin = req.Headers.Get("Origin");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(origin))
            {
                res.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            }
            if (req.Method == "OPTIONS")
            {
                res.StatusCode = 200;
                res.Headers.AppendCommaSeparatedValues("Access-Control-    Allow-Methods", "GET", "POST");
                res.Headers.AppendCommaSeparatedValues("Access-Control-    Allow-Headers", "authorization", "content-type");
                return;
            }
        }
        await next();
    });
    //other stuff
}
```

To enable Cors, follow the instruction [here](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html).

Answer (score 1):

When using OWIN middleware to handle CORS, we do not need to add headers on the WebAPIConfig or the web.config file. Yes, adding the headers on the web.config file does work when you want public access, but if you need to limit the access based on a whitelist (domains), then allowing **All** access is no longer what you would like to do.

With OWINS, we can handle this by implementing this handler:

```c#
OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.MatchEndpoint
```

With this handler, we can detect the request method (OPTIONS, POST...) and if the request should be treated as an Authorize or Token endpoint.  This is the area where logic can be added to check the Origin header (request) and validate if this domain should be allowed by adding the response header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```c#
string origin = context.Request.Headers.Get("Origin");
var found = IsDomainAllowed(origin);
 if (found){
      context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                             new string[] { origin });
 }
```

For more background on this, look at this link: http://www.ozkary.com/2016/04/web-api-owin-cors-handling-no-access.html

Answer (score 0):

Complete Soluction. You just need change some files, works for me.

**Global.ascx**

```c#
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    } }
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

*All the request has call this code.*

```asp
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        EnableCrossSiteRequests(config);
        AddRoutes(config);
    }

    private static void AddRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/"
        );
    }

    private static void EnableCrossSiteRequests(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
            origins: "*", 
            headers: "*", 
            methods: "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    } }
```

**Some Controller**

*Nothing to change.*

**Web.config**

*You need add handlers in you web.config*

```xml
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>   
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```