# asp.net web api 2 CORS and authentication authorization configuration

Tags: angularjs, azure, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I've created an asp.net web api 2 service with individual account security. I'm trying to call it form AngularJs as per this example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En
could not get that to work so added some config from here:
[How to make CORS Authentication in WebAPI 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079813/how-to-make-cors-authentication-in-webapi-2)

and can't get past this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'serverRegisterUrl'. 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'clientUrl, *, *', 
but only one is allowed. Origin 'clientUrl' is therefore not allowed access.

I don't understand this error message. I think that Access-Control-Allow-Origin string means allow origin clientUrl, all headers, all methods

I don't understand the problem. If I'm supposed to just specify the origin alone somewhere, I don't know where that is.

I'm running this on Microsoft Azure and using vs express for web 2013 update 2 just in case it matters.

I unfortunately had to take my links out of the error message because I need atleast reputation 10 here to post more then 2 links in a question.

Comment: in your API set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and it should work

Comment: I have this in my api web.config:

Comment: <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
does not work

Comment: (I have an asterisk for my value) -- still trying to figure out how to post here properly

Answer (score 10):

I got it working, I think it came down to configuration.
Web.config: no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" customHeaders node

Startup.Auth.cs:
`// This must come first to intercept the /Token requests`
`app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

`// Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users`
`app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);`

WebApiConfig.cs: (not enabling cors here)
`//var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");`
`//config.EnableCors(cors);`

AccountController.cs:
attribute on GetExternalLogin method:
`[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

---

I think that's my whole current CORS config.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding to @AlexSmotritsky's answer.

To make use of the **UseCors** method in

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

remember to install the Microsoft.Owin.Cors NuGet package and add the

**using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;** directive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value was `clientUrl, *, *` which might be invalid. It only allows one value. You can put `*` means all origins are allowed, or the one you specified, for example your AngularJS host.

I had put my code at https://gist.github.com/shaunxu/8414a78cd8074432fc69
This might not be the east way but it works in my application.

Comment: Thank you for your code. Depending on how I configure things around it I either get: 500 (Internal Server Error) or No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I'm going to figure out how to trace/log my service in azure as I don't know what's behind these 500 errors and I think I was generating them in some instances before I started using your class as well.

Comment: this is definitely an azure thing. my code works locally, 500 error happens in azure, will have to add error logging.