# CORS error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I am using an Angular front end to connect to a WEB API 2 backend. The failing use case is the following. When a user registers, on successful registration, they must be logged into the system and be redirected to a new page to collect further information. I am using TOKENS for authentication.

I have enabled CORS in the WebAPI config:

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:7812", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

The registration request is successful and the response headers have the required CORS headers:

```
**Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:7812**
Content-Length:0
Date:Sun, 24 Aug 2014 09:31:55 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcVGVzdGluZ1xNYWx0QXBhcnRtZW50c1xNYWx0YXBhcnRtZW50cy5BUElcTWFsdGFwYXJ0bWVudHMuQVBJXGFwaVxhY2NvdW50XHJlZ2lzdGVy?=
```

In the next step I attempt to log in the user to the system. As part of the login, the front end requests a TOKEN from the server at `Request URL:http://localhost:7802/token`. The request header once again sends a Origin header `Origin:http://localhost:7812` but this time I get the error : `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7802/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7812' is therefore not allowed access.`

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642293/asp-net-web-api-2-cors-and-authentication-authorization-configuration

Comment: Hi Mohammed - I tried all those steps - no success.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with CORS, we need to keep in mind that there may be two requests sent by the browsers for a non GET request. There is usually the preflight (OPTIONS) request and then the actual request (POST).  During the preflight requests, the server needs to add the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header with the value matching the request **Origin** header.  This authorizes the subsequent request to be sent.

For the subsequent/actual request, the server also needs to add the  **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header. Otherwise, this request fails.

When using the OWIN OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, we need to customize the **MatchEndpoint** handler to manage the header logic. This handler is executed before validate client authentication.

For more background information, look at this link: http://www.ozkary.com/2016/04/web-api-owin-cors-handling-no-access.html

Answer (score 1):

It's because of [Preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Read these articles for solutions:

- [How to make CORS Authentication in WebAPI 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079813/how-to-make-cors-authentication-in-webapi-2)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617892/Using-CORS-in-ASP-NET-WebAPI-Without-Being-a-Rocke

Comment: Yes, its a preflight request to get the token. I tried removing all the  code enabling CORS in the config code and putting it in the WEB config. The exception then changes to a HTTP 405 - Method not allowed but the config setting EXPLICITLY allows all methods ( <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />) Makes no sense at all

Comment: I usually use just OWIN configurations for CORS, but I think you should keep both: the EnableCorsAttribute with httpprotocol. if you want here is my solution: https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-api/blob/master/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L67

Comment: Thanks - I will look at your solution, however, I want to try and understand what the issue is before I go there. I have enabled CORS in the OWIN config and the WEB config and I get a new error saying there are multiple CORS headers. Understandable. So then I remove the WEB config settings. So at this point I only have the OWIN config active...Back to square one.... same error

Comment: @William - I have checked your code. My understanding at a basic level is that 2 things must happen. 1. The OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions must be set. 2. The app must call CORS (app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); I can see no special settings that apply to reflight requests. Since these are the only request types that are breaking, there musts be some additional information I am not aware of.

Comment: I've removed OPTIONSVerbHandler in web.config. https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-api/blob/master/Web.config#L94 see: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201211/Blog/Using-CORS-With-ASP-NET-Web-API/ and http://thoughtfulpractices.blogspot.it/2013/12/enabling-cross-origin-requests-cors-in.html

Comment: OK - I have enabled CORS in 1. My Startup, My WebAPI config, my Account controller AND in my Angular app. I have replaced the Web Config Handler with the new remove name = "OPTIONS" and tried with "OPTIONSVerbHandler". Nothing works. Anyway, I will leave you in peace now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you got two problems :

1- With Web API 2, you need to add the header manually when you grant the bearer token.

2- Your data needs to be url encoded, so you need to intercept the $http post message to encode the data.

refer to my article which I use Web API 2 from an AngularJS client side.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use these line in **web.config** :

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    ...
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    ...
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Its fixes my problem, may be it also help you.