# CORS ISSUE for mvc webapi

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am hosting MVC WebApi to godaddy server and client aplication also hosting to server and i am getting issue with

XMLHttpRequest cannot load my application The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://xxxxxx.in, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://xxxxx.in' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers to this question may provide you with what you need.

[asp.net web api 2 CORS and authentication authorization configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642293/asp-net-web-api-2-cors-and-authentication-authorization-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Enable cors in Webapi.config file

Webapi.config

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        // ...
    }
}
```

1. First * (aistrik) - For Allow  All Origins
2. Second * (aistrik)- For Allow All  headers
3. Third *(aistrik) - For Allow All methods

I think this would help you.