# SignalR Service 404 Hub

Tags: c#, windows-services, signalr

I have my SignalR Host in a simple Windows Service application.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    const string url = "https://localhost:8080";

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(typeof(MyHub).Assembly.FullName);

    using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
    {
        Log(string.Format("Device Hub started on {0}", url));
    }
}
```

Where `MyHub` is the name of my `Hub` class in a referenced console project and `Startup` is just

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    }
}
```

SignalR seems to start, but I keep getting a 404 Error on `https://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs`. I think it may not be recognizing the hub, but I can't quite figure out how to register it. Any suggestions?

** This exact code worked when running a console application, but seems to fail now that it is being accessed via a service **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check something like this:

http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.ch/2012/02/applying-and-using-ssl-certificate-with.html

It's not as simple as for http, or for https+IIS.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I read it more carefully and I think you have a major fault, you are calling your `Start` method inside a `using(...)` block, which means that you close your hosting immediately (the `OnStart` method exits). Remove your `using(...)` block and it should work (I tested it with http).

Also, the `AppDomain` stuff is not needed at all, given the fact that `MyHub` is referenced in your project.

Comment: I don't think the error is related to Http/Https, I think it is more directed at the service, which is hosting SignalR, is not able to find the hub in a referenced file.

Comment: That did the trick! I spent so long on that issue, I knew it had to be something simple that I was overlooking! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about the configuration: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079813/how-to-make-cors-authentication-in-webapi-2)
And just out of curiosity: does the hub work with HTTP only? (without SSL?)

**EDIT:** Change the url from `https://localhost:8080` to `https://127.0.0.1:8080` and try again.

Comment: The hub works currently in the console app over HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: But does the hub work from the Windows Service with http only?

Comment: What account is the windows service running as?

Comment: @Wasp, No, it does not.

Comment: @martin The service is running as Local System.

Comment: @FrankJohnson please look at my revised answer

Comment: I have switched in the Service, do I also need to switch it in the hub project to `https://*:8080`? And will I also need to switch the client as well?

Comment: Your service probably started OK but the reason you are not finding your hub probably lies in the IP protocol implementation. When service is running, it is running as Local System and that may be using your assigned IP (192.168.?.?) or 127.0.0.1 (default loopback). The same thing happens when you host your application in IIS - at that point it is only available through http://localhost from the local machine but not from remote machines. Something similar seems to be happening here. So yes, change all the addresses to the same string and try it out. If it works OK, else make a config file.

Answer (score 0):

change the port on your connection string to 443 like this

```
const string url = "https://localhost:443";
```

or not using ssl

```
 const string url = "http://localhost:8080";
```