# Enable CORS for ASP API Token request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cors, token

I have a project that has both an API and an Area that contains some web forms.
Recently the Token endpoint of the API started throwing CORS errors and I can't figure out why or how to fix it.

I've updated the Startup.Auth.cs file with:`app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

Also tried adding `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,POST"));` to the WebApiConfig.cs file.

Neither of these have added the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header that is needed.  (I do get a different error if both of these are implemented at the same time, so I know that is not the issue.)

Is there another location in the project that I need to set to allow CORS requests for an auth token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the problem(s).

First, my test harness was pointing at the wrong location so any changes I was making were having no effect and my break points were not being hit.  My bad.

Second, the configuration that finally got me working is to have the following code:

```
ApplicationOAuthProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials:
var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
if (allowedOrigin == null) allowedOrigin = "*";


WebApiConfig.Register:
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,POST"));
```

I hope this helps anyone else that is struggling with CORS and Katana/OWIN middleware.

Answer (score 2):

I had to this in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs/GrantResourceOwnerCredentials to work. The first three lines are for reference point only, "context.OwinContext" line was added to make it work.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            **context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "http://localhost:24589" });**
```

Use above if you want to individually configure and allow CORS at different access points. If you want to allow application wide then you may modify ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs/ConfigureAuth like below. Either approach works.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Comment: +1 The second approach is quick fix. You just have to add `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` nuget package. Another very informative thread on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079813/how-to-make-cors-authentication-in-webapi-2

Answer (score 1):

After enable CORS in WebApiConfig.cs , you should also config the web.config to also enable CORS . It's work in my application :

```
<system.webServer>
    <!--Enbale CORS-->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://yourwebsite" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules>
    ...
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled and spent around 5 hours, finally I got the solution.

Technology : Asp.net Framework

solution: need to install "Microsoft.Owin.Cors"

And Add the below line into "Startup.Auth.cs/ConfigureAuth()" method

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

we don't want to add anything in any where, this is sufficient and it is working fine for me.

I got the answer from here: [Getting token from web API2 from Angular2 leads to CORS issues or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211732/getting-token-from-web-api2-from-angular2-leads-to-cors-issues-or-null)