# Angular -> Web Api 2: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"

Tags: angularjs, api, azure, asp.net-web-api, cors

Basically I'm trying to access my web api which is uploaded on Azure.

I've added my CORS attribute to my WebApiConfig class:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:51407", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
```

However whenever I send an Ajax request (using angularJS) which rightfully contains

```
Origin: http://localhost:51407
```

I get the error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:51407' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue, you need to configure CORS-es. 
First go to "Web.config", find "system.webServer" tag, inside of it add next lines:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

That is all.

Answer (score 1):

For .NET server can configure this in web.config as shown below

```
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="your_clientWebUrl" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also work with webapi2 and AngluarJS client (different server) in Azure WebSites.

please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25758949/361100

If you cannot solve the problem, check other answers of the above link.