# ASP .MVC OWIN ExternalLogin and UrlRewrite

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

Application is hosted on 192.168.15.6.

With UrlRewrite accessed as https://some-site.com from internet

But after POST https://some-site.com/Account/ExternalLogin

1. Redirect is to **https://some-site.com/o/oauth2/** not to
   **https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/**
2. **redirect_uri=192.168.15.6/signin-google** not **redirect_uri=https://some-site.com/signin-google**

There are way to change this?

P.S. UrlRewrite module is work.

P.S. OWIN work too

P.S. Not work external login (Oauth) with UrlRewrite and OWIN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Rewrite Module (IIS) not working with OWIN Middleware hosted on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797323/url-rewrite-module-iis-not-working-with-owin-middleware-hosted-on-iis)