# Web API 2 EnableCors not working when I post data with DHC Chrome extension

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cors, asp.net-web-api2, dhclient

I am developing a Web API 2 project and I using EnableCors attribute like this:

**Controller:**

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:32454, http://localhost:25234", headers: "*", methods: "POST")]
```

**WebApiConfig:**

```
config.EnableCors();
```

**Web.config:**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

When I am posting data to my Web API via DHC Chrome extension, my controller is working fine. But, I set two origin. I don't want to access my Web API via DHC. Because, I didn't allow it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use Owin with Web Api and this should resolve:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I set specific "origin", "headers" or "methods" on Owin?

Comment: Sure Ahmet, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079813/how-to-make-cors-authentication-in-webapi-2) would help you to do that

Comment: I tried but, does not work for me. I can not run the Startup class.

Comment: Did  you install Owin ? Why u can't?

Comment: Yes, I installed Owin. Only I didn't write ConfigureOAuth method. But, doesn't work.

Comment: Ahmet, please, check if your Configuration method is fiering when you start the application, if it is now make sure you have this above your namespace: `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]`