# Calling Web API method in postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call the following Web API method in Postman:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllNotifications(HttpRequestMessage request, String Name)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try
            {
                List<ExpandoObject> res = _userProcess.GetAllNotifications(Name);
                response = request.CreateResponse<List<ExpandoObject>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, res);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Unable to process your request Please contact administration");
                throw new DataException(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And you may want to format your code so it is readable...

Comment: Formatted code.

Comment: Here's a detailed description on how to authenticate the user and then communicate with the api through post ma
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976982/authorize-attribute-authentication-with-postman-in-web-api/42978131#42978131

Comment: How to call GetAllNotifications method in User Controller in Postman GET and POST Request

Answer (score 0):

Just run your Project in localhost and copy the Url from the Browser and add 
your Api name , Example if the Project runs with an url like : https://localhost:3000/api/values

Just change the url with your api name in place of "values"
https://localhost:3000/api/GetAllNotifications and now paste this url in postman and set get method and click on send make sure your project is running in the same localhost port Number.