# Asp.Net Cors returns headers on OPTIONS but not on GET request

Tags: asp.net, http, cors, owin

Using `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` in a .Net Mvc *(not core)* project I configure cors on startup like this:

```
var cors = new CorsPolicy {
  AllowAnyHeader = true,
  SupportsCredentials = true,
};
cors.Origins.Add("http://localhost:3006");
cors.Methods.Add("GET");
cors.Methods.Add("POST");
cors.Methods.Add("PUT");
cors.Methods.Add("DELETE");
cors.Methods.Add("OPTIONS");
app.UseCors(new CorsOptions {
  PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider {
    PolicyResolver = ctx => Task.FromResult(cors)
  }
});
```

When I do a cross-origin query from a site on localhost:3006 I get a successful OPTIONS preflight request followed by a successful yet blocked GET request.

[image: OPTIONS followed by a blocked GET]

When I inspect the response, I see

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: authorization
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3006
```

on the OPTIONS response, but not on the GET!

Why on earth not? What do I need to make it work correctly?

Comment: Not sure but you have added Origins URL as http:// and request is being made with https://.    Also, there seems to be some gotchs in seeing the cross origin headers    https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @Hoax that's not helpful at all - as I specified I am *not using core*. The core libraries have quite different APIs. More importantly, nothing in that link addresses that content of this question - why would the preflight succeed but the actual fail?

Comment: @mukeshjoshi same thing as I told hoax - as the question makes clear I am *not* using core. The idea that you have to register it before Mvc is an interesting thought, but I have no clue how that fits within the non-core pipeline

Comment: can you please check  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32294458/2416451

Answer (score 0):

So after plugging at this for a full day I finally got it working. I couldn't get it working using the Owin handler. The hint for me is that OPTIONS succeeded but GET failed.

What I suspect is that on .Net Framework, Mvc actually happens outside of the Owin pipeline, as it ties directly into System.Web. While I'm sure sure there's a way to fix that by messing with my web.config, in my case I really *only* need CORS for my web api handled routes, therefore switching to `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` did the trick.